# Magento Localhost Installation - LAN Works - WAN Issues?

Tags: networking, router, localhost, wan, loopback

I’m new to home servers and Magento. Running Ubuntu Server 13.04 with LAMP and Magento Commerce 1.7.0.2 on a dedicated home server. I've already configured my server's static IP, router's firewall and port forwarding, and am running ddclient on my server to sync my router's dynamic IP with namecheap.com (my domain name and nameserver provider).

When I use a static index.html page, the page loads from my localhost using my server's static IP. The page also loads on the WAN using my router's IP and domain name (through either a proxy website or on my smartphone cell network). Using the proxy website helps avoid loopback timeouts. This narrows down the issue to Magento.

While using http://{localhostIP}/ as my base URL in Magento and loading Magento's index.php, I was able to access the file locally with my server's static IP. But, when accessing Magento over the WAN using my domain name or router's IP, it says "not available, HTTP Error 504: Gateway Timeout".

So then I tried adding my domain name as a base URL in Magento. Now I can access Magento over the WAN but not the LAN. Did anyone figure out a way to resolve this issue?

The only two threads I could find on the issue haven't been resolved or updated recently: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/273640/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/212885/

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your webserver didn't resolve WAN IP. Let 's fix this problem by consider WAN IP as an vhost. Let 's add this code to your virtual host file of web server

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "<your web folder>"
    ServerName <your IP here>
    ErrorLog "logs/<your IP>-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/<your IP>-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```